# Lebesgue-Stieltjes measure associated to $g$

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-measures

I what to prove this statement

[image]

But it seems to me that is part from the definition, here is the definition:

[image]

I mean; if $a<b$ then $A=(a,b] \in B(\mathbb{R})$ then
$\mu_g(A)=\mu_g((a,b])=g(b)-g(a)$. So there is something I do not get? because for example what is the continuous from the right part for?

Edit:[image]

I understand that they refer this example, but this uses the outer measure but is not necesay in this case, isn't it?

Comment: Right continuity would be required if you want to prove that $\mu$ is countably additive  on the class of finite disjoint unions of half open intervals.

Comment: Yes, but for the purpose of the excercise 17, What is the difference from the definition to what is requested?

Comment: The exercise 17 refers to "Example 9.19". Could you post "Example 9.19"?

Comment: I make the edit.

Answer (score 1):

I'll illustrate with an example: Let $g : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a function defined by
$$
g(x) = z
$$
for all $x \in [z,z+1)$, where $z \in \mathbb{Z}$. Note that
$$
\bigcup_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} [z,z+1) = \mathbb{R},
$$
and it is a disjoint union, so it is a partition of $\mathbb{R}$. So $g$ is well defined.

The continuous from the right part is satisfied, but it is not continuous from the left. So
$$
\mu_g((z,z+1]) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} g(z+1-h) - \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} g(z+h) = z - g(z) = z - z = 0,
$$
for every interval of the partition, for this definition of $g$. Do you get where the continuous from the right part is used?

Disclaimer: if you see any mistake, edit it, I'm responding via cellphone.